# Does IntelliJ Community Edition support CFML plugin?

Tags: coldfusion, intellij-idea

I know the premium edition has a CFML plugin, but does the Community Edition? I really need to get away form using Eclipse. If all else fails I can use the Premium trial for the time being.

Comment: Good catch on the typo. I missed that when fixing the capitalization/abbreviations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This plug-in is available only in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition.

Answer (score 0):

CFML/Coldfusion plugin in not available for IntelliJ Community edition.
Available only on IntelliJ Ultimate Edition.

Answer (score -2):

I would use Sublime Text 2, available here [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/2)

There is a very good ColdFusion plugin available for it not to mention the entire plugin ecosystem it has.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.